# Can I break fast for my high school graduation?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

As most of you know, we are currently in the holy month of Ramadan, I'm a high school senior and my graduation is tomorrow.

It starts at 10 AM and I must wake up at 7 AM

Since I reside in Dubai, our Maghreb prayer is at 7:15 PM

I'm wondering if it would be permissible for me to break fast tomorrow and fast again for this day after Ramadan is over considering tomorrow is a very tiring day with long hours until Iftar. Do note that since I am in Dubai, the temperature reaches 50 celcius and generally it's very tiring.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impermissible to forgo even a single fast provided it is not detrimental and harmful to your health.

It being a tiring and exhausting day is not a valid reason to quit/forgo Ramadan's obligatory fast.

Comment: It would complete your answer to add some sort of references.

Comment: It wasn't required by OP hence it precisely answers the question.